# Calling a base class method from a base class

Tags: python

When I call method1() from the outer class, it ends up calling the derived class method1() instead.  How can I force it to call the base class method1?  Is it best for the inner class to have an **init** and from there call the parent **init**?

```
class OuterClassA
    __init__
       method1()

    def method1(self):
        ....

class InnerClassB(OuterClassA)

    def method1(self):
     ....
```

Answer (score 3):

Python's double underscores name mangling is designed to help with this issue.

For the details and a worked-out example see: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables and at http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers .

```
class OuterClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__method1()      # call this class's private copy

    def method1(self):
        ...
    __method1 = method1       # make a private (class local) copy


class InnerClassB(OuterClassA)
    def method1(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the base class `method1()`.

```
OuterClassA.method1(someClassBObject)
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the preferred approach to the problem.

Comment: The preferred solution is to not run into this in the first place. The asker has decided that avoidance is no good, so the rest is figuring out which bleepy solution is the least horrible.

Comment: There are legitimate use cases for wanting to let a subclass override a method without interrupting the parent's ability to make direct internal calls.